# How to view NTLM challenge in Network View?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, ntlm

In chrome dev tools, how do i see all elements of a request, specifically the working of the Ntlm challenge?

Ex. If i do a GET to a URL and the server issues a NTLM challenge, there are multiple requests and responses - the initial challenge, the response to it and the re-run of the original request with the Authorization header.

What i see in chrome is only the final element, the final request with the auth header added (if auth worked of course).

I'm able to capture the whole cycle via Fiddler or looking at the server. Just want to know if there's a way to see it via dev tools in Chrome (or any other browser), a view or setting i'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a demo page where I can try out this NTLM challenge myself?

Answer (score 1):

Could not find a way to do this in Chrome as well.

Instead of using Fiddler I tried Curl.

```
curl http://intranet_url -v --ntlm --negotiate -u USER123:PASSWORD123 -o output.txt --trace-ascii output2.txt
```

For the username you can use:
gary.thom@contoso.com (user principal name)

sources:

[Using curl with NTLM auth to make a post is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697157/using-curl-with-ntlm-auth-to-make-a-post-is-failing)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats