# NTLM authentication in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ntlm, http-authentication

In my Haskell program I need to talk to a server that requires NTLM authentication. I know this because the server answers

```
401 ... WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

to my request. When I access the website in Chrome and trace the HTTP conversation it's obvious that a challenge-response authentication of some sort is taking place.

Is there a way to perform this kind of authentication in Haskell? Previously I've been using the **req** library to do HTTP requests but it doesn't seem to support NTLM authentication. I also understand that NTLM requires re-using a single TCP connection for all traffic once the connection has been authenticated. I don't see any obvious way of making that happen in **req** from my reading of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this and don't know NTLM, but it looks like the [libcurl bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl) have what you need.

Maybe you could use them to construct something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21435035/6629874) with it. You could try:

```
curlGet "http://url.com" [CurlHttpAuth [HttpAuthNTLM], CurlUserPassword "username:password"]
```

Comment: In the end, libcurl worked out great. Thanks for your help!